# Check for matching data in cells in same row?

Tags: excel, match, vba

VBA Newbie here.  In order to perform a quality check on an upload of information, I need to check certain rows of information to see if the strings input in Columns D & F are the same -- if not, I would like to highlight the row and pop up a message box.

These particular rows of information I need to check are indicated by a string in Column H.

Formula answers are welcome, but I would prefer for this to be in VBA since the information is always changing and the rows I need to look into are always changing.

Here's what I'm working with so far:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sEmail As String
Dim sName As String
Dim rStr As String
Dim bAllClear As Boolean

bAllClear = True
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Upload")

With ws
For i = 1 To 20 'For testing - this needs to be a dynamic range from _
                '1 to end of content
    If .Cells(i, 8).Value = "Completed" Then
        sEmail = .Cells(i, 7).Value
        sName = .Cells(i, 5).Value & " " & .Cells(lRow, 6).Value
        If .Cells(i, 4).Value = sEmail Then
        Else
            .Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 8)).Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            bAllClear = False
            rStr = rStr & sName & vbNewLine
    End If
    End If
Next i

If bAllClear = True Then
MsgBox ("All clear!")
Else
MsgBox ("The following learners have mismatched emails between the learner and rater columns." _
        & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & sName & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Please double check to make sure each name is listed correctly before continuing.")
End If
End With
End Sub
```

[image: Data sample]

My code above isn't catching that Robert Baratheon in Column G is listed next to Aerys Targaryen in Column D.  Unfortunately I have a terrible history of convoluting very simple tasks, and I may be doing so here.  Two Qs then: 1) How can I make my range dynamic?, and 2) What am I doing wrong in my code?

Comment: If the two cells need to be the same, why collect and upload them twice?

Comment: @DougGlancy Columns B-D are deleted before the file is uploaded. They exist to help ensure the lists in E-G are grouped correctly and have all the correct information. I wish I were looking for a better system, but unfortunately I was only tasked with automating the current one =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have removed unnecessary variables. Also I noticed that you were showing `sName` in the final message box. I guess you wanted to show `rStr`

Is this what you are trying?

```
Const sMsg1 As String = "The following learners have mismatched " & _
                        "emails between the learner and rater columns."

Const sMsg2 As String = "Please double check to make sure each " & _
                        "name is listed correctly before continuing."

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sName As String, rStr As String
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Upload")

    rStr = ""

    With ws
        '~~> Find last row in Col H
        lRow = .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lRow
            If .Cells(i, 8).Value = "Completed" Then
                If .Cells(i, 4).Value <> .Cells(i, 7).Value Then
                    sName = .Cells(i, 5).Value & " " & .Cells(i, 6).Value
                    '~~> Coloring Red
                    .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 8)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    rStr = rStr & vbNewLine & sName
                End If
            End If
        Next i

        If rStr = "" Then
            MsgBox ("All clear!")
        Else
            MsgBox (sMsg1 & _
                    vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    rStr & _
                    vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    sMsg2)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**OUTPUT SAMPLE**

[image]

Comment: Oh Siddharth, you're always answering my questions =).  I ended up adding `Option Compare Text` so it ignores case sensitivity and everything works great.  I was having a bit of difficulty because I had some conditional formatting that already highlighted rows that said "Completed" (as seen above), so instead I decided to bold and change the text color.  But this totally gets done exactly what I need, so thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help :)